# blocks in beamer inside a tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I want to create a block showing this or any other text while simulation.How do I do it inside a `\begin{tikzpicture} ... \end{tikzpicture}`

edit: like in one slide it will say `clk is 0`, in the next `clk is 1`. here I did it with a `\node` command. How do I do it with   `\begin{block} ... \end{block}` inside the `\begin{tikzpicture} ... \end{tikzpicture}`

This is not the same as this question : [transition in tikzpicture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/442305/transition-in-tikzpicture) 
because I want to enclose the text in a block diagram[image added for reference below], not in a node.

[image]
[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes.gates.logic.US,shapes.gates.logic.IEC,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles} %<-added
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\setbeamercovered{dynamic}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (0,0) rectangle (10,7); % Use this to set the dimensions to approximately the page size
    \begin{scope}[shift={({1},{5})}]


        \node(J) at (1,0) {$J$};
        \node[nand gate US,draw,logic gate inputs = nnn,thick] at ($(J)+(2,0)$) (Nand1){};

        \node(K) at ($(J)+(0,-2.5)$) {$K$};
        \node[nand gate US, draw, logic gate inputs = nnn,thick] at ($(K)+(2,0)$) (Nand2) {};

        \node[nand gate US, draw, logic gate inputs = nnn, thick,anchor=input 1] at ($(Nand1)+(3,0)$) (Nand3) {};
        \node[nand gate US, draw, logic gate inputs = nnn, thick, anchor = input 3] at ($(Nand2)+(3,0)$) (Nand4) {};

        \draw(J) |- (Nand1.input 2);
        \draw(K) |- (Nand2.input 2);
        \path (J) -- (K) node[midway] (CLK) {$CLK$};

        \draw (Nand1.input 3) --++(180:5mm) coordinate (aux) |- (CLK);
        \draw (CLK-|aux)|- (Nand2.input 1);

        \draw(Nand1.output) |- (Nand3.input 1);
        \draw(Nand2.output) |- (Nand4.input 3);

        \draw (Nand3.output) -- ([xshift=2cm]Nand3.output);
        \draw (Nand4.output) -- ([xshift=2cm]Nand4.output);

        \draw (Nand3.output) --++(0:2cm) node[right](Q) {$Q_n$} coordinate[pos=.25] (aux1) coordinate[pos=.5] (aux2);
        \draw (Nand4.output) --++(0:2cm) node[right] (QN) {$\overline{Q_n}$} coordinate[pos=.25] (aux3) coordinate[pos=.75] (aux4);

        \node[visible on=<{2}>](out1) at ($(Q)+(0.5,0.5)$) {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{Q}}};

        \node[visible on=<{3}>](out1) at ($(Q)+(0.5,0.5)$) {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{0}}};
        \node[visible on=<{4}>](out1) at ($(Q)+(0.5,0.5)$) {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{1}}};
       % \node[visible on=<{5}>](out2) at ($(Q)+(0.5,0.5)$) {\textcolor{red}{{$\overline{\textbf{Q}}$}}};

       \node[visible on=<{2}>](out2) at ($(QN)+(0.5,0.5)$) {\textcolor{red}{{$\overline{\textbf{Q}}$}}};

       \node[visible on=<{3}>](out2) at ($(QN)+(0.5,0.5)$) {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{1}}};
       \node[visible on=<{4}>](out2) at ($(QN)+(0.5,0.5)$) {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{0}}};

        \node[visible on=<{2,3}>](in1) at ($(J)+(0.5,0.5)$) {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{0}}};
        \node[visible on=<{4}>](in1) at ($(J)+(0.5,0.5)$) {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{1}}};

        \node[visible on=<{2,4}>](in2) at ($(K)+(0.5,0.5)$) {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{0}}};
        \node[visible on=<{3}>](in2) at ($(K)+(0.5,0.5)$) {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{1}}};

        \node[visible on=<{5,6,7,9}>](in1) at ($(J)+(0.5,0.5)$) {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{1}}};
         \node[visible on=<{5,6,7,9}>](in2) at ($(K)+(0.5,0.5)$) {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{1}}};

         \node[visible on=<{6,7,8}>](out1) at ($(Q)+(0.5,0.5)$) {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{1}}};
         \node[visible on=<{6,7,8}>](out1) at ($(QN)+(0.5,0.5)$) {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{0}}};

         \node[visible on=<{6,7,9}>](out1) at ($(CLK)+(0.5,0.5)$) {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{1}}};

         \node[visible on =<{6}>]  at($(CLK)+(4,-4)$) {\text{CLK IS 1}};

         \node[visible on=<{7,8}>](out1) at ($(Nand1)+(0.5,0.5)$) {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{1}}};
         \node[visible on=<{7,8}>](out1) at ($(Nand2)+(0.5,0.5)$) {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{0}}};

          \node[visible on=<{8}>](out1) at ($(Nand3)+(-0.75,0.5)$) {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{1}}};
           \node[visible on=<{8}>](out1) at ($(Nand4)+(-0.75,-0.5)$) {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{0}}};

            \node[visible on=<{9}>](out1) at ($(Nand3)+(0.75,0.5)$) {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{1}}};
             \node[visible on=<{9}>](out1) at ($(Nand4)+(0.75,-0.5)$) {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{1}}};

        \draw (Nand2.input 3)--(Nand2.input 3-|aux)--++(-90:5mm)-|(aux2);
        \draw (Nand1.input 1)--(Nand1.input 1-|aux)--++(90:5mm)-|(aux4);

        \draw(Nand4.input 1) --++(180:5mm) --++(90:3mm) -- ([yshift = -3mm]aux1) --(aux1);
        \draw(Nand3.input 3) --++(180:5mm) --++(-90:3mm) -- ([yshift = 3mm]aux3) --(aux3);

        \foreach \i in {CLK-|aux,aux1,aux2,aux3,aux4}
        \filldraw (\i) circle (1.5pt);
    \end{scope}     
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: While you wait for an answer to this question, can you go back to your previous ones and look if the answers solve your problems and accept them, if they do?

Comment: And regarding this question: can you please include a mock-up how the slides should look like? As it stands I don't really understand what layout you have in mind.

Comment: @samcarter i did accept the previous answers :/

Comment: and adding a mock up of the slides wait

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/442305/transition-in-tikzpicture https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/440332/colored-row-in-beamer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/440302/drawing-logic-gate-circuit-with-tikz-library https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/440287/how-do-i-simulate-a-logic-circuit-in-latex all don't have an accepted answer :( see also [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)

Comment: Thank you for accepting the answers to your previous questions!

Comment: Does the question @Zarko linked to, solve your problem?

Comment: no, that question was also asked by me. im editing the question again since its not clear to many

Comment: as i can see, the linked answer contain all what you need to solve this question, if something is not clear in this code, ask in comment there.

Comment: @Zarko please see the edit

Comment: now is not duplicate but unclear what you asking for ... sorry :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Not sure if I understand the question*

I would simply place the blocks below the tikz image.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes.gates.logic.US,shapes.gates.logic.IEC,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles} %<-added


\usecolortheme{orchid}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\setbeamercovered{dynamic}

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
%\draw (0,0) rectangle (9,5); % Use this to set the dimensions to approximately the page size

        \node(J) at (1,0) {$J$};
        \node[nand gate US,draw,logic gate inputs = nnn,thick] at ($(J)+(2,0)$) (Nand1){};

        \node(K) at ($(J)+(0,-2.5)$) {$K$};
        \node[nand gate US, draw, logic gate inputs = nnn,thick] at ($(K)+(2,0)$) (Nand2) {};

        \node[nand gate US, draw, logic gate inputs = nnn, thick,anchor=input 1] at ($(Nand1)+(3,0)$) (Nand3) {};
        \node[nand gate US, draw, logic gate inputs = nnn, thick, anchor = input 3] at ($(Nand2)+(3,0)$) (Nand4) {};

        \draw(J) |- (Nand1.input 2);
        \draw(K) |- (Nand2.input 2);
        \path (J) -- (K) node[midway] (CLK) {$CLK$};

        \draw (Nand1.input 3) --++(180:5mm) coordinate (aux) |- (CLK);
        \draw (CLK-|aux)|- (Nand2.input 1);

        \draw(Nand1.output) |- (Nand3.input 1);
        \draw(Nand2.output) |- (Nand4.input 3);

        \draw (Nand3.output) -- ([xshift=2cm]Nand3.output);
        \draw (Nand4.output) -- ([xshift=2cm]Nand4.output);

        \draw (Nand3.output) --++(0:2cm) node[right](Q) {$Q_n$} coordinate[pos=.25] (aux1) coordinate[pos=.5] (aux2);
        \draw (Nand4.output) --++(0:2cm) node[right] (QN) {$\overline{Q_n}$} coordinate[pos=.25] (aux3) coordinate[pos=.75] (aux4);

        \node[visible on=<{2}>](out1) at ($(Q)+(0.5,0.5)$) {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{Q}}};

        \node[visible on=<{3}>](out1) at ($(Q)+(0.5,0.5)$) {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{0}}};
        \node[visible on=<{4}>](out1) at ($(Q)+(0.5,0.5)$) {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{1}}};
       % \node[visible on=<{5}>](out2) at ($(Q)+(0.5,0.5)$) {\textcolor{red}{{$\overline{\textbf{Q}}$}}};

       \node[visible on=<{2}>](out2) at ($(QN)+(0.5,0.5)$) {\textcolor{red}{{$\overline{\textbf{Q}}$}}};

       \node[visible on=<{3}>](out2) at ($(QN)+(0.5,0.5)$) {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{1}}};
       \node[visible on=<{4}>](out2) at ($(QN)+(0.5,0.5)$) {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{0}}};

        \node[visible on=<{2,3}>](in1) at ($(J)+(0.5,0.5)$) {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{0}}};
        \node[visible on=<{4}>](in1) at ($(J)+(0.5,0.5)$) {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{1}}};

        \node[visible on=<{2,4}>](in2) at ($(K)+(0.5,0.5)$) {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{0}}};
        \node[visible on=<{3}>](in2) at ($(K)+(0.5,0.5)$) {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{1}}};

        \node[visible on=<{5,6,7,9}>](in1) at ($(J)+(0.5,0.5)$) {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{1}}};
         \node[visible on=<{5,6,7,9}>](in2) at ($(K)+(0.5,0.5)$) {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{1}}};

         \node[visible on=<{6,7,8}>](out1) at ($(Q)+(0.5,0.5)$) {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{1}}};
         \node[visible on=<{6,7,8}>](out1) at ($(QN)+(0.5,0.5)$) {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{0}}};

         \node[visible on=<{6,7,9}>](out1) at ($(CLK)+(0.5,0.5)$) {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{1}}};

%         \node[visible on =<{6}>]  at($(CLK)+(4,-4)$) {\text{CLK IS 1}};

         \node[visible on=<{7,8}>](out1) at ($(Nand1)+(0.5,0.5)$) {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{1}}};
         \node[visible on=<{7,8}>](out1) at ($(Nand2)+(0.5,0.5)$) {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{0}}};

          \node[visible on=<{8}>](out1) at ($(Nand3)+(-0.75,0.5)$) {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{1}}};
           \node[visible on=<{8}>](out1) at ($(Nand4)+(-0.75,-0.5)$) {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{0}}};

            \node[visible on=<{9}>](out1) at ($(Nand3)+(0.75,0.5)$) {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{1}}};
             \node[visible on=<{9}>](out1) at ($(Nand4)+(0.75,-0.5)$) {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{1}}};

        \draw (Nand2.input 3)--(Nand2.input 3-|aux)--++(-90:5mm)-|(aux2);
        \draw (Nand1.input 1)--(Nand1.input 1-|aux)--++(90:5mm)-|(aux4);

        \draw(Nand4.input 1) --++(180:5mm) --++(90:3mm) -- ([yshift = -3mm]aux1) --(aux1);
        \draw(Nand3.input 3) --++(180:5mm) --++(-90:3mm) -- ([yshift = 3mm]aux3) --(aux3);

        \foreach \i in {CLK-|aux,aux1,aux2,aux3,aux4}
        \filldraw (\i) circle (1.5pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{block}<8-9>{}
\centering
clk is \only<8>{0}\only<9>{1}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: apparently you have a crystal ball, that you know, what is the question ...  :-)

Comment: @zarko That would actually be a nice addition to the tikzmarmots package: crystal balls ;-)

Comment: @marmot Unfortunatly there are no crystal balls left to give to the ducks - this site depletes the whole supply!

Comment: @Zarko Actually I didn't understand the question either, this was just a lucky guess :)

Comment: @samcarter I am [not sure about that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOr3L.png)... ;-)

Comment: @marmot, i agree, but unfortunately i'm horrible poor drawer :-(

Comment: @Zarko That does not matter, as long as it works ;-)